# How to change the shape circle to square on any selecting and hover on any date in mat-datepicker in angular

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I want to change the shape of selecting and hovering on any date to square instead of circle

[this is the calendar i need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbTw6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite tricky the first time.
For the hover effect:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell {
    &:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled) {
        &:hover {
            >.mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
                &:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected) {
                    &:not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
                        // add your styles here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled):hover > 
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(.mat-calendar-body- 
selected):not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
     // your styles here
}
```

For the selected day:

```
.mat-calendar-body-selected {
    // add your styles here
}
```

And in case you need it, for the circle that shows the day you are in:

```
.mat-calendar-body-today {
    &:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected) {
        &:not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
            // add your styles here
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected):not(.mat- 
calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
     // your styles here
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need a css, how to change it from circle to square

Comment: done @Dante try it please

Comment: can you suggest me a styles what you are using for that i cant see here

Comment: I dont really know what you want to do, use the element inspector in chrome and modify the element as you need

Comment: hey can you please give me one more help i didnt able to change the color of preselected today date it I want to change it, it come up as permanetly